# How to supress Solution1 save prompt in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

Almost every time I close SQL Server Management Studio I get a prompt that asks if I want to save "Solution1".  My understanding is that solution files are deprecated; in fact I've recently tried to use SQL solution files but decided against it because they are almost impossible to manage in the current UI.

Does anyone know how to force SSMS to let go of solutions once and for all, and stop asking me to save?  This prompt is a real annoyance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft sez "CLOSED: WONTFIX" 
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=124686

Comment: This is not good news, but it definitely answers the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its coming in SSMS 2016! This does, however, include the individual query files, too, not just the Solution you and I were looking for.
https://web.archive.org/web/20160420021521/http://www.ksdit.com/sql-2016-skip-prompting-save/

Comment: That site was talking about the prompt to save the SQL scripts in the query windows, but the question was about the prompt to save the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Download this [version 13.0.15800.18](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) of `Sql Server Management Studio 2016` with many fixes, including save solution on exit suppressed.

Answer (score -1):

Don't fight the current... and create a solution.. and store yoru scripts in that solution!
:-)

Comment: I hate to accept this as an answer, but it looks like this does take care of the problem.

Comment: Nah. Hate to say it, but that sucks. DBAs frequently fire off tons of ad-hoc stuff. I _GET_ why SSMS is treating those scripts and such like a solution. BUT, MS is dropping the ball here and trying to force users to behave like they want them to behave. Instead, they should be making the solution work like users want/need. In my mind, this is one reason why the 'studio' experience for SQL Server Management Studio was a HORRIBLE path for MS to take.